# Recuperación de código en Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Acabo de cometer un error fatal con mi proyecto, por error eliminé una parte del código bastante extensa y compleja y guardé los cambios, quisiera saber si alguien sabe cómo puedo ver el historial de cambios realizados o algo parecido para poder recuperar esa parte del código, estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2017 y en lenguaje C#, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: de casualidad utilizas Git o TFS ?

Comment: Si tienes versionado el proyecto y que ese archivo haya tenido esos cambios versionados es posible recuperarlos, de otra forma, me temo que no será posible recuperar la información borrada.

Comment: Estas usando Git?

Comment: No estimado :/ , no estoy usando GIT

Comment: yo te recomiendo que no guardes ningun fichero ni nada. Busca alguna aplicación de restauracion de archivos borrados tipo Undelete Plus y cruza los dedos.

Comment: 1. Para ahora mismo todo lo que estés haciendo
2. Aprende Git: https://git-scm.com
3. Pon TODOS tus proyectos en repositorios de Git
4. Créate una cuenta en GitHub (https://github.com/) y sube todos esos repositorios como proyectos privados
5. Dame las gracias la próxima vez que vuelvas a perder código y puedas recuperarlo sin más que volver a bajarte el repositorio 

Comment: @Konamiman, tus consejos son perfectos para mantener el código seguro y co nregistros de todas modificaciones, pero eso es un consejo para futuro y no es lo que necesita actualmente el usuario.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Y precisamente por eso los he publicado como comentario y no como respuesta a la pregunta. :-)

Comment: Suena tonto, pero ya revisaste la papelera de Windows? Normalmente cuando borras desde VS, no borras permanente, se va a la papelera de windows

Comment: Lo último que podrías hacer es usar una herramienta de recuperación de archivos como Disk Drill: teniendo en cuenta que el archivo ha sido borrado recientemente las posibilidades de recuperarlo son altas (siempre y cuando no estés guardando cosas nuevas en el disco; una vez que recuperes el archivo considera aprender Git).

Answer (score 0):

La única posibilidad real es que hayas efectuado un compilado de tu proyecto, por ejemplo, si por de casualidad tienes un dll del proyecto antes de que efectuaras el borrado, podrías intentar abrirlo con el add-in Reflector y obtener de ahí el código que te has eliminado, caso contrario no podrás obtenerlo a menos de que utilices un sistemas versionador.